# Why is Powershell erroring after successful TAP tests?

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, tap, appveyor

I'm running Node test on Windows with Appveyor, and hitting a problem in one environment only: Powershell with Node 0.10.

In the other Node versions I get output like this:

```
npm test # PowerShell
#...

TAP version 13
# find rc file in third searched dir, with a package.json lacking prop
ok 1 should be equal
ok 2 first dir: checked /a/b/c/d/e/f/package.json
ok 3 first dir: checked /a/b/c/d/e/f/.foorc
# ...

1..72
# tests 72
# pass  72

# ok

npm test
# ...
```

But in Node 0.10.40, with npm 1.4.28, I get this:

```
npm test # PowerShell
#...

TAP version 13
# find rc file in third searched dir, with a package.json lacking prop
ok 1 should be equal
ok 2 first dir: checked /a/b/c/d/e/f/package.json
ok 3 first dir: checked /a/b/c/d/e/f/.foorc
# ...

1..72
# tests 72
# pass  72

# ok

npm : 
At line:1 char:1
+ npm test # PowerShell
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

C:\projects\cosmiconfig\test\a\b\foo.config.js:1
quire, module, __filename, __dirname) { module.exports = { found: true: false,
                                                                      ^

Command executed with exception: C:\projects\cosmiconfig\test\a\b\foo.config.js:1
quire, module, __filename, __dirname) { module.exports = { found: true: false,
                                                                      ^
```

That line of code it's complaining about is a deliberate error -- part of the test -- which is (I believe) caught and handled, and the test is to make sure that error happened.

Why would Node 0.10 on Windows only (this doesn't happen on Unix via Travis) have this problem? What do I need to do to fix it?

(If you need other details to troubleshoot please let me know: I don't know enough about what's going wrong to know what to share.)

Comment: The error just saying, that application write something in its error stream. You can do `cmd /c npm test '2>&1'`, so that error stream will be redirected in standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like old versions of npm write some things to stderr though they don't actually exit the process with an error code. As @PetSerAl said, Powershell will error when this happens, but other terminals will not. The solution seems to be just not to run those tests in Powershell.

cf. http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/2347-npm-275prefer-global-warning-causes-failure-command-executed-with-exception and https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8517